# Rephrase a multiparameter SDE indexed by time and space as an infinite dimensional SDE indexed by time

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Let $\mathcal V_t\subseteq\mathbb R^3$ be the bounded space occupied by a closed particle system at $t\ge 0$ and $$[0,\infty)\ni t\mapsto X_t\in\mathcal V_t\tag 1$$ be the movement of a fixed particle $X_0\in\mathcal V_0$ over time. Assuming that the motion of $X_0$ is perturbed by space-time white noise, we may assume that $${\rm d}X_t=v_t{\rm d}t+\xi_t{\rm d}B_t\;\;\;\text{for all }t\ge 0\tag 2$$ for a smooth resolved velocity $v$, a random unresolved component $\xi=(\xi^1,\xi^2,\xi^3)$ and a $\mathbb R^3$-valued Brownian motion $(B_t)_{t\ge 0}$.

> Letting $\Phi_t(X_0):=X_t$ and $u_t(X_t):=v_t$, we obtain $${\rm d}u=\left(\partial_tu+(u\cdot\nabla)u+\frac 12\langle C,C\rangle u\right){\rm d}t+\nabla u\cdot\xi_t{\rm d}B_t\;\;\;\text{for }t\ge 0\tag 3$$ with $C:=\sum_{i=1}^3\xi^i\partial_i$ and $u=u_t(X_t)$ by a well-known Itō formula.

Instead of considering the multiparameter SDE $(3)$ for the $\mathbb R^3$-valued process $u$ indexed by time and space, I would like to write down an infinite dimensional SDE for a process indexed by time only and taking values in a infinite dimensional Hilbert space $H$ of functions in space.

$H$ will be some Sobolev space, e.g. $H=H_0^1(\mathcal V\to\mathbb R^3)$ where $\mathcal V$ is the union of the $\mathcal V_t$ up to some finite time $T\ge 0$ (which is assumed to be bounded and open).

> What do I need to do? I tried to perturb the fluid flow map $\Phi$ by a $H$-valued cylindrical Brownian motion $(W_t)_{0\le t\le T}$, i.e. I've tried to assume that $${\rm d}\Phi_t=u_t(\Phi_t){\rm d}t+\xi_t(\Phi_t){\rm d}W_t\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in [0,T]\;,\tag 4$$ but I don't know how I need to proceed. I think I need to apply some kind of Itō formula in order to find an expression for $u_t(\Phi_t)$ as I did with $(2)$ to obtain $(3)$.

Comment: @oxbadfood : Maybe you could have a look at le LNM by Filipovic "Consistency Problems for Heath-Jarrow-Morton Interest Rate Models" "http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/b76888" best regards.

Comment: @TheBridge Could you please explain why you think I should take a look at this book?

Comment: @oxbadfood : If I remember well the authors is studying infinite dimensional stochastic calculus with variables taking value in Hilbert space, and is deriving such things as Itô's formula in the context. Best regards

Comment: @TheBridge Thanks for your effort, but there are many books on infinite dimensional SDEs and I'm aware of a suitable Itō formula for them. The problem is, that they are only applicable for Itō processes, but here (in $(4)$) the integrands on the rhs depend on $\Phi_t$.